# For each Sub Directory write a separate file (csv) with information

Tags: powershell

I have a situation where I need to write an Output file for each folder with data/information within each folder.

**Folder/directory structure:**

```
C:\Logs\15Sec\Ref.Data\Month\Log.Jan\Day.1\
~\Month\~ have folders up to Log.Dec
~\Log.Jan\~ has a folder for 30/31 Days in a month
~\Day.1\~ has files with data
```

**What I could achieve:**

I can read data using a script for all Days in a month and can write the info in a CSV file. thanks to @zett42.

This works fine at the given folder/directory structure -

```
C:\Logs\15Sec\Ref.Data\Month\Log.Jan\
```

**Script:**

```sh
$targDir = "C:\Logs\15Sec\Ref.Data\Month\";
$subDir = $(Get-ChildItem "$targDir" –Directory );
foreach($sub in $subDir) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $sub –Recurse *.log | 
    Select-Object -Property @(
        'FullName'
         @{ Name = "LineCount"; Expression = { 
             (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 8 | Measure-Object).Count
         }} 
    ) |
    Export-Csv C:\test\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

**Problem:**

When trying to run the script at a higher folder/directory structure, which is

```
C:\Logs\15Sec\Ref.Data\Month\
```

The script only writes the Output file for the last folder present in Month for example Log.May. All other folders (Log.Jan, Log.Feb, etc) information will not be written. I don't know how to do this and couldn't trace the correct help on the internet.

**Expectation:**
A separate file for each Month with the name of the month (Log.Jan.csv, Log.Feb.csv) itself.

Comment: Why are you using Recurse? Get-ChildItem -Path $sub –Recurse *.

Comment: I read on a webpage that this helps to get through subdirectories.

Comment: Where do you want to create the csv file? In `C:\test`? If so, change to the export to `Export-Csv "C:\test\$($sub.Name).csv" -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: @arco44 your suggestion does the job for me.

Comment: You already have the subdirectories using Get-ChildItem.  You do not need to get them again.

Comment: @jdweng looks to me like both `Get-ChildItem`s are required. One to get the 1st level dirs under `Month`, then the second to recursively get all the dirs in each month directory (inside the foreach loop) - this info is processed and added to the csv

Comment: @arco444 : Get child items will get every folder.  So why would use need to get the descendant a second time using recurse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script currently writes the output for *every* month, but also overwrites it on every loop iteration - that's why you only see data from the last month. So you just need to update the output path to grab the name from the current month's directory.

Change the export definition to:

```
Export-Csv "C:\test\$($sub.Name).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```